# Is there a way to populate the inverse relationship when using ActiveRecord builder methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I wanted to use the [ActiveRecord association builder methods](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) to build an **in memory** object. I expected the has_many association of the starship object to contain the crew member object.

Is this possible, or an expected limitation of ActiveRecord?

```
require 'active_record'
require 'minitest/autorun'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  adapter: "sqlite3",
  database: ":memory:",
)

ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  create_table(:starships)
  create_table(:crew_members) { |t| t.references :starship }
end

class Starship < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :crew_members, inverse_of: :starship
end

class CrewMember < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :starship, inverse_of: :crew_members
end

class BuilderTests < MiniTest::Test
  # fails
  def test_build_association_populates_both_sides_of_the_relationship
    refute_predicate CrewMember.new.build_starship.crew_members, :empty?
  end

  # fails
  def test_create_association_populates_both_sides_of_the_relationship
    refute_predicate CrewMember.create.create_starship.crew_members, :empty?
  end

  # passes
  def test_association_is_not_empty_when_saved_and_reloaded
    crew_member = CrewMember.create
    starship = crew_member.create_starship

    assert crew_member.changed?
    assert_predicate starship.crew_members.reload, :empty?

    crew_member.save!

    refute_predicate starship.crew_members.reload, :empty?
  end
end
```

My use case is kinda flimsy, and this was more a curiosity I observed and wondered if it was possible, or simply wishful behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

`build_association` does *not* yet save the object, you must use `create_association` if you want to achieve that, or manually saving the `crew_member.starship` instance. So the main reason you get to see `crew_member.starship` is because it is in memory, but since it wasn't persisted yet, there is no connection between the two. More on [association docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-belongs-to-build-association-attributes)

Comment: This is a fair point, I've updated my example to take into account persisting the objects, although my question does specify whether this is possible to do in memory only.

To clarify in order for create_association to work, `autosave` must be specified, or the belongs to model must also be saved (demonstrated in my last test above)